# What changes in laws and regulations have there been in the last few years concerning food safety and allergy contamination in prepared foods?

Tags: england-and-wales, health, food, restaurants, food-processing

Recently there seem to have been a change in the legal requirements in restaurants in serving customers that have food allergies. What instruments could have contained this?

Comment: What do you mean by "What instruments could have contained this?" Other than the corresponding regulatory bodies (from Parliament to lower levels) passing some laws or not passing others, which kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @SJuan76 I assume it's a reference to statutory instruments

Comment: Well I actually thought that instruments could refer to a broader category they may also encompass statutory instruments but more broadly include all types of legislative instruments or articles in all their forms (ie regulations, instruments, acts of Parliament, orders, etc). Rick will know fit sure whether this is mistaken use of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent significant change that springs to mind is the mandatory labeling for pre-packed for direct sale (PPDS) food if it contains any of '[the 14 allergens](https://www.food.gov.uk/business-guidance/allergen-guidance-for-food-businesses)'.

PPDS food is prepared and packaged on the same premises from which it is offered, including products behind a counter, in a display unit or from mobile or temporary outlets, or prepared on one premises and sold elsewhere by the same operator. It includes sandwiches, baked goods, salads, pasta pots and pizzas that are packaged.

They must have an ingredients list and any allergens must be emphasised each time they appear in the list.

Distance sellers are not required to individually label the food but they must make the allergen information available to the consumer before purchase and at the moment of delivery.

The change to law was the [Food Information (Amendment)(England) Regulations 2019 No 1218](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2019/1218/contents/made), aka [Natasha's Law](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-58756597), which came into effect on 1 October 2021.

Before then it was not obligatory to individually label such food with allergen information.

Natasha Ednan-Laperouse was a 15 year old who died in 2016 after suffering an allergic reaction to an undeclared ingredient (sesame) in a Pret a Manger baguette.

There have been a number of The Food Information Regulations, Food Labelling Regulations and such.

https://www.legislation.gov.uk/primary+secondary?title=Food%20Information

These Regulations amend subordinate legislation such as the The Food Safety and Hygiene (England) Regulations 2013.